# How to have the result of a UNION overwrite a table records

Tags: ms-access

I am a beginner in SQL.  I would like the results of a UNION of linked tables tblCandidates and tblCandidatesArchive to overwrite the data in tblInvites.   This UNION works:

```
SELECT tblCandidates.INPUT_NUMBER, tblCandidates.Booked, tblCandidates.Call_1, tblCandidates.Call_2, tblCandidates.Call_3, tblCandidates.Call_4, tblCandidates.[BizO RESULTS], tblCandidates.CallResults_1, tblCandidates.CallResults_2, tblCandidates.CallResults_3, tblCandidates.CallResults_4
FROM tblCandidates

WHERE (((tblCandidates.Call_1)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidates.CallResults_1)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidates.CallResults_1)="Biz Overview")) OR (((tblCandidates.Call_2)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidates.CallResults_2)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidates.CallResults_2)="Biz Overview")) OR (((tblCandidates.Call_3)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidates.CallResults_3)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidates.CallResults_3)="Biz Overview")) OR (((tblCandidates.Call_4)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidates.CallResults_4)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidates.CallResults_4)="Biz Overview"))

UNION 

SELECT  tblCandidatesArchive.INPUT_NUMBER, tblCandidatesArchive.Booked, tblCandidatesArchive.Call_1, tblCandidatesArchive.Call_2, tblCandidatesArchive.Call_3, tblCandidatesArchive.Call_4, tblCandidatesArchive.[BizO RESULTS], tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_1, tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_2, tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_3, tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_4
FROM tblCandidatesArchive

WHERE (((tblCandidatesArchive.Call_1)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_1)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_1)="Business Overview")) OR (((tblCandidatesArchive.Call_2)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_2)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_2)="Business Overview")) OR (((tblCandidatesArchive.Call_3)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_3)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_3)="Business Overview")) OR (((tblCandidatesArchive.Call_4)>Date()-366) AND ((tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_4)="eMailed Info" Or (tblCandidatesArchive.CallResults_4)="Business Overview"))
ORDER BY tblCandidates.Call_1 DESC
```

But as soon as I add this to the beginning of the SQL query statement it errors with a long syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(((tblCandidates.Call_1)>Date()-366) and

```
WHERE(((tblCandidatesArchive.Call_)>Date()-366) AND('.


INSERT INTO tblInvites (INPUT_NUMBER, Booked, Call_1, Call_2, Call_3, Call_4, [BizO Results], CallResults_1, CallResults_2, CallResults_3, CallResults_4)
```

It took me a while to get the UNION working.  I looked at the suggested links when posting.  I also Googled.  I am having problems finding anything which does exactly what I am trying to do.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'overwrite'? Cannot use a UNION query as source for an UPDATE action. So maybe you should first DELETE all records from tblInvites then use UNION as source for INSERT SELECT action.

Comment: Hi JNevill.  Yes, I figured out how to delete first using a different query.  That works, so that is no longer  an issue at this time.

Comment: But, the posted INSERT statement above is still notworking.

Comment: The INSERT statement syntax is not correct. There is no phrase for the data source. Needs to be like either 1) `INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (data)` or 2) `INSERT INTO table/query(fields) SELECT fields FROM other table/query`. The INSERT cannot follow UNION statement in same query object.

Comment: Yes, I am putting the INSERT INTO tblInvites statement as the first line, followed by the SELECT... FROM... WHERE... UNION SELECT... FROM... WHERE.... ORDERED BY.  Do I still have something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

An all-in-one statement using UNION as data source for an INSERT SELECT must follow syntax like:

```
INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) SELECT field1, field2 FROM (union query SQL here)
```

The UNION data source is a nested SQL without a terminating semi-colon between parentheses.